# Free video conversion software that supports widescreen format

Tags: video, software-rec, conversion, widescreen, hdvideo

Is there a good video conversion software for Windows that supports widescreen format?

Things I tried from download.com don't support widescreen. It creates black bars top and bottom.

I like AVS Video Converter, but it isn't free. Is there a good free one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Handbrake](http://handbrake.fr/?article=download) handles this well on both OSX and Windows. Also you can do it with [ffMpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) directly as well.

Answer (score 2):

I've used [SUPER](http://www.erightsoft.com/SUPER.html) and had good results, but some people are leery that it might be a bit suspicious (so, be careful and make you're you're only downloading from the developer's site).

It's basically a front-end to the ffmpeg library, which can do anything and everything video-related.

Answer (score 2):

This really depends on your skill and if you want to use command line or not. [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) is the swiss army knife of tools for video conversion and most tools simply are a wrapper around it.

I wrote an open source UI for ffmepg  to convert windows media centre files to the iphone is up on codeplex [here](http://ipodconverter.codeplex.com/) there is a binary download, but the source would need tweaking to do what you want. But you can't argue with the price.

Answer (score 1):

[winff](http://winff.org/html_new/) is a GUI for ffmpeg and is really good at converting everything into everything. I am yet to find something that I needed that it didn't do

Answer (score 0):

if you're converting directly from dvd or dvd image, I can recommend [DVDx](http://www.labdv.com/dvdx/).