# How can I burn a mov file to a DVD?

Tags: windows-7, macos, software-rec, dvd-burning

If I have a `*.mov` file on my hard-drive, how can I burn it to a DVD disk so that I can pop that into a DVD player and play?

I have Windows 7 and OS X.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way is to use a program like iMovie, iDVD, or Toast.

Comment: How to get that to work? I tried 'import a mov' to my iMovie project, but it does not let me burn to a dvd. the 'Share option' is greyed out.

Comment: Sorry for assuming the gui apps were self explanatory.  iMovie is your "creation" application.  After importing your media, you have to use it in a project.  Create a project from the menu and then add your media to the project.  At that point you should be able to go to the share movie and send the project to iDVD.  iDVD is what actually burns the media to disk.  If for some reason the iDVD option under the iMovie share menu is greyed out, just skip iMovie and create the dvd directly in iDVD.  You wont get the editing capability of iMovie that way though.

Comment: Here is an even easier way with iDVD.  Start iDVD. Click the File Menu, then Click One Step DVD From Movie.  Select your .mov file and hit next.  Voila.  No menus, just a DVD that plays.

Answer (score 0):

An **MOV** file is a QuickTime media container format in order to play in DVD player you need to convert it to the format that DVD player support mostly **.avi**

[Free video converters](https://superuser.com/questions/6165/free-video-conversion-software-that-supports-widescreen-format)

Comment: Hmm, actually, DVD players don't support "avi". It's rather the codecs contained within, like DivX or XviD (both MPEG-4 visual). Converting to "avi" only works if the codec is one of the aforementioned and the DVD player really supports it. Handbrake can do that, but it won't output AVI files! Otherwise one should burn it as a normal video DVD using MPEG-2 and a DVD authoring software.